# Check if cell contents contain a string from a list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with reports that contain competitive data, and I'm trying to delete any row where the cell in column `D` does not match a list of strings specified in a different sheet. This is what I have so far, and while it works, it is incredibly slow. Is there a faster or more efficient way to do this?

```
Dim product As String
Dim TempArray as Variant
Dim idArray() As Variant
Dim myTable As ListObject


Sub rambler()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    populatingArrays
    filterID
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub populatingArrays()

    Sheets("Competitive Set").Activate
    Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    TempArray = myTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1)
    idArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)

End Sub

Sub filterID()

    Sheets("Report").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Activate

        Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
          product = ActiveCell.Value
          IsInArray = UBound(Filter(idArray, product))

          If UBound(Filter(idArray, product)) < 0 Then
             ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
           Else
             Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
          End If

        Loop

    ActiveSheet.Name = "I&D Data"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

NOTES: I know I shouldn't be using Activate and Select, but I'm not sure how to make this work without them. Another thing, this code is partly copy-pasted, and I'm not sure what `IsInArray` is or does, but all rows get deleted when I remove that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't see a reason to use global variables.  Let's scope those to their respective subs.

Secondly, let's say your "Report" sheet has data in `D2:D100`, where cell `D101` is the first empty cell.  Therefore, you're trying to loop through range `D2` to `D100`, and checking if the filter applies.

Third, I am passing arguments to the subs to keep the scopes as local as I can. (I'm also doing this without testing, but I think it should work...)

If that's correct, I think this should run quicker for you:

```
Option Explicit 'Forces you to declare all variables. This goes at the very top of the Module.
Sub rambler()
dim myArr as Variant
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    myArr = populatingArrays
    filterID(myArr)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function populatingArrays() as Variant
Dim idArray() As Variant
Dim TempArray As Variant

    Set myTable = Sheets("Competitive Set").ListObjects("Table1")
    TempArray = myTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1)
    idArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
    populatingArrays = idArray

End Sub

Sub filterID(arr as Variant)
Dim product As String
Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

With Sheets("Report")
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1 ' Deleting rows: it's best to start at the end and work up.
          product = .Cells(i, "D").Value
          IsInArray = UBound(Filter(arr, product))

          If IsInArray < 0 Then
             .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
          End If
    Next i
    .Name = "I&D Data"
End Sub
```

Edit: See if you can understand how I removed the uses of `.Select`.  Also, one great thing to learn/understand is how to pass a parameter to a subroutine.  I also changed the `Sub populatingArrays()` to a `Function`, which allows us to return some value (whereas with the `Sub`, to do the same, you'd need a Global variable).  Stepping through this with <kbd>F8</kbd> should help a lot in seeing how it works.